# Проверка значения поля таблицы БД

Tags: php

Как проверить значение конкретного поля в таблице БД? допустим, чтобы поле act в таблице user было true

Comment: Не бывает "значение поля таблицы". Бывает только "значение поля конкретной записи таблицы". А тех записей там как на собаке блох - где-то true, где-то false, где-то вообще null... Так что надо бы определиться, на какую из записей смотреть.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE act='true'
```

И проверяете сколько строк нашлось, грубо `mysql_num_rows`, например.